# substitution of whipping cream for water in jello

Tags: gelatin

This is the first time I have been on the internet for over 5 years so please excuse my slowness with this site.  I have been successful using heaving whipping with unflavored gellatin mix  with added sugar and vanilla.  I have used both a mold and a big crystal bowl, depending on how much I was serving and how much I made.  May I substitute heavy whipping cream instead of water to make flavored jello or gellatin mix.  I would now like to use lemon or strawberry flavored jello or some other flavor of jello mix that has the sugar in it and the color to make a desert and use the directions as if using water.  To enhance it, I use fresh fruit or even cooked preserves such as raspberries or sour cherries.  This desert is called "Russian Cream".  I am also thinking of using lemon curd to put on the side, which is where one would put the cooked preserves or drizzle on top, slice fruit, lemon curd, whatever sounds good to you.  Other additions can be added to  the unflavored gellatin to make it lighter like half and half (diet version) or bolder like cream cheese or even slice up fruit very small, dry and mix.

#### Update in answer to comments---Here I am again with news of what has happened with the substitution.  It came out okay.  I realized I had to play with the sugar as the gellatin mix or "Jello or Jelly" already had sugar in it.  I did heat up the cream and mixed things up accordingly and put in the fridge.  I looked up Pannacotta and found that different various versions resembled what I was making, Russian Cream.  It is interesting that various cultures have the similar versions of same things and I realized that Flan was also included in this mix.  Today I made the original and nothing beats it.  Thanks for the adventure of the site.

Comment: Why do you want to use whipping cream instead of water? What do you hope will happen?

Comment: How about something like this instead: http://sweettreatsmore.com/2012/03/super-easy-creamy-jell-o-dessert/

Comment: Here's the "official" kraft version: http://www.kraftrecipes.com/recipes/creamy-layered-squares-62754.aspx

Comment: Do you mean that you've done exactly this with unflavored gelatin and it works? I can't imagine the addition of flavoring is going to mess that up.

Comment: @Catija Could be it's easier for the OP to find cream than cool whip, if they're not in the US? But yes, user33210, if you're just trying to ask "how do I make a creamy jello thing?" you can just ask that!

Comment: That's certainly possible... Like you, I think their question is a bit confusing... and I think only Americans call it "Jello"... They call it Jelly in the UK.

Comment: You'll get the most consistent results if you use a real pana cotta recipe instead of trying to figure out ratios and process by yourself.

Comment: This was merely a substitution question of unflavored gellatin to flavored gellatin mix, not water for cream.  I wanted to make something decadent with what I had on hand. I had heavy whipping cream that I wanted to use not cool whip, and this was not the time or the place for plain, I wanted rich.  Another thing added, if wanted, is cream cheese to the mix just to confuse your guests in a good way.  It was all good in the end, but no, I will not do it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason why not. Some chef's cheat when making pannacotta and simply set some flavoured milk with geletin.

Simply replace all the water with cream. It may set a little firmer so you might want to tinker with the recipe next time round. The result will be somewhere between panna cotta and blancmange.

I'd suggest warming some of your cream with the geletin mixture in order to dissolve it completely then mix it with the remainder of your cream.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of recipes on the web for making creamy jello.

There seem to be a few options including:

- [Method 1](http://www.kraftrecipes.com/recipes/creamy-layered-squares-62754.aspx) - Using the quick-set method, add 8 oz of defrosted whipped cream topping (cool whip) after icing the Jell-o.
- [Method 2](http://www.lowcarbfriends.com/bbs/showthread.php?t=761676) - Using the regular or quick set method, replace some of the cold or cool water with cream
- [Method 3](http://www.madefrompinterest.net/jello-ice-cream-shamrocks/) - Using the regular or quick set method, replace some of the cold or cool water with melted ice cream

The links take you to examples of recipes with more in-depth discussion of the specifics but there are many others out there.